# Yii - how to preload a widget

Tags: yii, preload

I am working with Yii Jui widgets to have JuiTabs in a website. The problem is when the site is loading I first see the list (without any css) and then after the page loads the tabs show as they should. I wonder if there is a way to preload JuiTabs somehow so they show correctly when the page is loading.

Here is my code:

```
         <?php 
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
                    'tabs'=>array(
                        'PRESENTAZIONE'=>array('content'=>$this->renderPartial('spettacoli/_view_presentazione', array('model'=>$model),$this)),
                        ...
                    ),

                    'options'=>array(
                        'collapsible'=>false,
                    ),
                ));
            ?>
```

And [here](http://marionette-cola.linkmesrl.com/laboratorio/viewproduzione) is the example of the page. The problem is visible when the internet connection is slow, and it takes time until the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that's possible to preload JuiTabs somehow, but you can add `display: none` for CJuiTabs by default and show that with JS on page load. Not the best way, but first idea came into my mind.